# How to get and/or set the link key when pairng bluetoth devices using Android(Java)?

Tags: java, android, bluetooth

I'm really new on this of Android development, so I have many questions. Right now I'm trying to connect two devices via Bluetooth. So far I was able to do this, I have connected two tablets, but now I'm asked to save the LinkKey and use some bytes of it to create a PIN. So, how can I get that LinkKey? I've read that it's saved on both devices for future connections, but I don't know how to get it.

Also, I've read that this devices can delete those LinkKey, what happens then? If they try to connect with each other again, will they use the same LinkKey or a new one is created?

And the last thing. I have to connect a tablet to a device that has neither a display nor a keypad, a normal bluetooth connection is enough? I'm doing this to stablish the connection:

```
final UUID MY_UUID = UUID.randomUUID();
        //tmp = device.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(MY_UUID);
        Method m = null;
        try {
            m = device.getClass().getMethod("createRfcommSocket", new Class[] {int.class});
        } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        tmp = (BluetoothSocket) m.invoke(device, 1);
        mmSocket = tmp;


    Thread connectionThread = new Thread(new Runnable(){

    public void run() {
        // Cancel discovery because it will slow down the connection
        mBluetoothAdapter.cancelDiscovery();

        try {
            // Connect the device through the socket. This will block
            // until it succeeds or throws an exception
            mmSocket.connect();
        } catch (IOException connectException) {
            // Unable to connect; close the socket and get out
            try {
                mmSocket.close();
            } catch (IOException closeException) { }
            return;
        }

        // Do work to manage the connection (in a separate thread)
        manageConnectedSocket(mmSocket);
    }
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Link key creation is done on the stack/LMP(Link Manager) level, not on the app level. Bluetooth devices check if the link key exist or not, if exist, it will not go for pairing and bluetooth connection will proceed, if no link key is found on the bluetooth stack, LMP(Link Manager) will initiate a new pairing process , once pairing completed, bluetooth connection will proceed. If link key is deleted, a new link key will be generated for a connection.

Try checking in adb shell (`/data/misc/bluetoothd` or `data/misc/bluetooth`) for link key , it will be available in the paired device info.